# Is this proposed change to the Transmutation Wizard's Master Transmuter class feature balanced for a setting without resurrection? [Version 2]

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, balance, wizard, homebrew-review

In my [previous iteration of this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160506/35259), I proposed a replacement for the Master Transmuter option ***Restore Life***. the feedback I received identified that it was too powerful, so I have a new, much simpler proposal. The brief description below outlines the problem; see my other question for a more detailed explanation.

---

The [School of Transmutation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofTransmutation]) wizard archetype has a feature at level 14 called Master Transmuter. It can allow such a wizard to, once per long rest, destroy their transmuter's stone and do one of a handful of options, one of which is:

> ***Restore Life.*** You cast the *[raise dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/raise-dead)* spell on a creature you touch with the transmuter's stone, without expending a spell slot or needing to have the spell in your spellbook.

Unfortunately, in my homebrew universe, there is no resurrection magic, so I'm looking into replacing this option with something homebrew that is not related to resurrection, but still at least broadly fits the theme of "***Restore Life***".

---

Still considering *[greater restoration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration)*, I wonder if it would be balanced to simply allow ***Restore Life*** to cast it instead of *raise dead*, a direct trade with no other additions (i.e. not a "super charged" version like I proposed before)?

> ***Restore Life.*** You cast the *greater restoration* spell on a creature you touch with the transmuter's stone, without expending a spell slot or needing to have the spell in your spellbook.

My reasoning behind believing that this might be balanced, in light of the feedback, is a) it's a 5th level cleric spell like *raise dead*, and b) it is not usually available to wizards, same as *raise dead*.

One the other hand, I'm concerned that this might be a bit weaker than the RAW *raise dead* version of ***Restore Life*** (after all, once you're dead, *greater restoration* can't help at all), and the fact that, in the context of curses specifically, *greater restoration* can end *one* curse, whereas the ***Panacea*** option can end *all* curses.

If that is true (that my proposal is weaker that RAW), I'm also considering waiving the costly material component of the *greater restoration* spell if cast in this way, since it seems [you do need it for the *raise dead* version](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91000/35259). If this is not weaker (or waiving the material component would make this vastly more powerful), then I won't do that.

---

So my question is, in a setting where there is no resurrection magic, does my new proposed replacement of the ***Restore Life*** option of the Master Transmuter class feature seem balanced?
Ideally contrasting with and without my "waive the material costs" suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is a balanced replacement for the previous option

This answer draws heavily on my answer to the [previous post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160506/is-this-proposed-change-to-the-transmutation-wizards-master-transmuter-class-fe).

Seeing as this option replaces a "free" (minus the cost of components) cast of a 5th level spell (*Raise Dead*), with a different 5th level spell (*Greater Restoration*), I think that this is a balanced replacement.

Unfortunately, the more I think about it, the fact that this is a balanced replacement for the previous *Raise Dead* doesn't mean that it will be used all that often.

### I don't think that players will use it much

While examining the two iterations, it's become clear to me that the *Panacea* option itself is absurdly overloaded and will probably outshine this option in all but the rarest of cases.

*Panacea*, with its ability to cleanse *all* curses, poisons, and diseases, while restoring *all* hit points, will almost always be the go-to in-combat option for the Master Transmutation feature. There will be cases, of course, where *Greater Restoration* could be more useful, however in the general case I think *Panacea* is too strong to ignore.

As such, I foresee this option being used infrequently at best. Of course, this could be perfectly fine, as many of the other options are very situational. I just know that I guiltily enjoy seeing my players make use of my homebrew material, so if you're like me, you might get greater satisfaction out of further reworking this effect so that it is more generally useful.

### Opinion: this option should be reworked into an out-of-combat or an over-time effect

After further consideration, it seems to me that the original *Restore Life* option was geared more as an out-of-combat ability. After all, *Raise Dead* has a casting time of one hour, [regardless of whether it is cast using Transmutation Master](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152287/how-much-time-does-the-restore-life-property-of-a-transmuters-stone-take).

I think that, with some fiddling, you could probably come up with a appropriate way to redefine this ability as an option that matches *Panacea*'s power but as an effect that takes longer to cast.

An easy way to do this would be to extend the casting time of your previous iteration for this ability from 1 action to 1 minute (1 effect per turn?) or 1 hour, depending on how you envisage the ability being used.